# Mouse Pad For MadCatz M.M.O. 7

Tags: mouse-pad

What's the best mouse pad for me?

Especially for Counter Strike: GO

My settings are:

- Mouse: MadCatz M.M.O. 7
- Mouse driver dpi: 800
- Windows dpi: standard
- Acceleration: off
- Mouse grip: palm
- Finger set: 1+2+2

I know that for some mouses coloured pads might not be the best option.
Any size will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've had excellent luck with the razer goliathus, assuming you want a 'soft' mousepad.

I've had a few others but this has a few features that make it a decent choice.

The edges are stitched, so it won't split. This is a *critical* feature in terms of long term use. I've had lesser gaming mousepads have their top surface peel off.

You have two options for surfaces - If you're a *twitch* gamer, go for the slick surface of the [speed varient](http://www.razerzone.com/sg-en/gaming-mouse-mats/razer-goliathus-speed-edition), if you want more control (and I'm guessing from the relatively low DPI, you're a *precision* player) there's the [control version](http://www.razerzone.com/sg-en/gaming-mouse-mats/razer-goliathus-control-edition).  I've got both (on different systems) and I'm relatively happy with both.

There's multiple sizes (I went with large on the speed pad, small on the control version) to suit your playing style as well.

Comment: Can you tell in what way does those 2 versions differ? speed one is like easier to move or what?

Comment: Yes, since its smoother.